# Selenium Webdriver - PhantomJS hangs upon send_keys() to file input element

Tags: python, browser, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am performing some file uploading tests. I found that my test code hangs at `element.send_keys(file)` if I am using PhantomJS, however the same code does not hang if I am using Firefox.

```
element = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
element.send_keys(file)
```

Is there any workarounds to make PhantomJS upload files properly? Currently I am using Windows 7, Python 3.4.1, selenium 2.42.1, PhantomJS 1.9.7.

Comment: Could you tell if the input had an attribute muliple

Comment: The input do have "multiple" attribute.

Comment: I have the the same problem with PhantomJS when you do the send.keys(file). I hadn't had any luck moving forward, What I could tell is selenium is not driving html5 page that good. We cannot directly set the value of the input using send_keys. We need to open the upload browser dialog window, in your case if u have one, and fill in the filepath using external Automation API like AutoIT etc because the webdriver has no clue about the dialog window at all as its under the OS doamin level. I know this is a hassle, but I tried executing javascript, Action builder none worked.

Comment: Also, if possible try using a different browser like chrome or firefox as its easy to debug, since phantomjs is a headless browser.

Comment: happens even without the "multiple" element

Comment: Is the input hidden?

Answer (score 1):

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1200,800)
```

Without setting the window size, the browser remains in mobile size causing errors. Try a implicit wait too.

Answer (score 0):

Should use PhantomJS.uploadFile(). However, didn't find python selenium API.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');   
var page = webPage.create();
page.uploadFile('input[name=image]', '/path/to/some/photo.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough i couldn't get anything to run in my ubuntu shell but it would run via iPython from Jupyter notebook on the exact same server.

I had to add a virtual display into the code to make it run from the shell as a .py script...

if it helps anyone facing the similiar problem here is the lines of code i added to my script and the send keys start to work without an issue.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

# Set screen resolution to 1366 x 768 like most 15" laptops. This is needed 
#to run in the shell. Seems fine in iPython
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach when I can not simply change the value of the file input tag.

We will run it console, so we should use [PyVirtualDisplay](https://pypi.org/project/PyVirtualDisplay/) with window manager *(I am using **dwm**, you can try **fluxbox** it is easy to install but need more RAM then dwm)* and Xephyr for debug.
To run window manager we will use [EasyProcess](https://pypi.org/project/EasyProcess/)

So we will call File Upload Dialog, by clicking on element or button, then we simulate send keys with [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) and all these running in our console.

```
import time

from easyprocess import EasyProcess
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class ImageUploadAutomation:
    chrome = 'path/to/chrome'
    chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,900")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
        "excludeSwitches", ["disable-popup-blocking"]
    )
    chrome_options.add_argument(
        "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled"
    )

    driver = None

    def upload(self, photo):
        # Change visible to 1 if you want to use Xephyr debug
        with Display(visible=0, size=(1280, 900)) as display:
            with EasyProcess(["dwm"]) as process:
                keyboard = Controller()
                url = "https://www.exmaple.com"

                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
                    executable_path=self.chrome,
                    chrome_options=self.chrome_options
                )
                self.driver.get(url)

                test = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "//div[@aria-label='Add Photos']"
                )
                time.sleep(1)
                test.click()

                time.sleep(1)

                for key in photo.path:
                    keyboard.press(key)
                    keyboard.release(key)

                # keyboard.press(Key.enter)
                with keyboard.pressed(Key.enter):
                    pass
```